# CSS writing-mode doesn't work for some characters

Tags: css

CSS writing mode doesn't work for some characters, in particular for symbol '№'. Here example

```
<html>  
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p style="writing-mode: vertical-lr;">
      Номер № 2
    </p>
  <body>    
</html>
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/3pc5ihz5

All symbols are rotated and only this symbol not changed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace   `Номер № 2` with    `Номер N° 2`

This is a known bug with some symbols

Comment: _Is_ it a bug?  Firefox and Chrome seem to behave the same way, so I'm wondering if it's something more intentional...

Answer (score 1):

It's not only about this symbol, even the HAN characters (characters of chinese, japanese, korean laguage) does not rotate with writing-mode: vertical-rl.

```
<html>  
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;">
       ニュース
    </p>
  <body>    
</html>
```

Check this for more info : https://www.w3.org/International/articles/vertical-text/index

Answer (score 0):

`№` is not the only symbol, which won't change, there are more.
Some symbols are just not supported.